# Inserting POST data in to a sorted array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to insert the post data from multiple inputs in to an array.

**screenshot of the view**
[image]

Here is the code from my View

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'roster/sequence'))}}
<h3>Generate Roster Sequence</h3>
<desc>Please enter your sequence below.</desc>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Morning</th>
        <th>Evening</th>
        <th>Night</th>
        <th>Off</th>
    </tr>

    @for ($d = 1; $d < 8; $d++)
        <tr class="tbrow">
            <td>{{ "Day ".$d}}</td>
            @for ($s = 1; $s < 5 ; $s++)
                <td>
                    <div class="textbo">
                    @for ($n = 0; $n < 5 ; $n++)

                        {{-- */  $name = "".$d.":".$s.":".$n;    /* --}}
                        {{ Form::text($name)}}

                    @endfor
                    </div>
                </td>

            @endfor


        </tr>

    @endfor


</table>


<p>
    {{ Form::submit('Create Sequence', array('class'=>'button medium')) }}


    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
</p>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Controller fetches data from post as below**

```
public function storesequence(){

    $input = Input::except('_token');;

    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        //echo "".$value."::::".$key;
        list($day, $shift, $slot) = explode(":", $key);

        echo "day is : ".$day."shift is: ".$shift." slot is : ".$slot." value is::::".$value."</br>";

    }

}
```

**End goal is**
To achieve an array which represents data as below:

```
 day : shift1: shift2: shift3: off
 1   :  1,2,3   4,5,6   7,8,9  10,11
```

I am not quite sure how I can do that, and thus I am here asking you guys. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You really should post your output html. It is much easier to help if we can see the code of the form you want to post.

Comment: I have already shown the code for the form !!